# Javascript - Compare and find uncommon elements' indexes in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two 2d arrays as below. Both have same length and their elements also have same length.

```
const array1 = [
  ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
  ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
  ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
  ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,569.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
  ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTE", "Test1"],
];

const array2 = [
  ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
  ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTG", "Test1"],
  ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
  ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
  ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,500.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
];
```

While the array1 is ordered, array2 is not. I need to find the indexes in array1 and array2 where the elements have different values like

```
output: [{6, 5}, {1, 5}], [{5, 4}, {6, 4}]
```

I tried the below code to get the rows that are different in both array1, array2 but couldn't figure out how to find the column indexes.

```
const findDifferentElements = (array1, array2) => {
  var indexesInArray1 = []
  var indexesInArray2 = []
  const diffInArray1 = array1.filter(each => !array2.includes(each))
  const diffInArray2 = array2.filter(each => !array1.includes(each))
  console.log(diffInArray1, diffInArray2)

  // find indexes of diff elements
  diffInArray1.forEach(each => indexesInArray1.push(array1.indexOf(each)))
  diffInArray2.forEach(each => indexesInArray2.push(array2.indexOf(each)))

  console.log(diffInArray1.forEach(each => array1.indexOf(each)))
  console.log(diffInArray2.forEach(each => array2.indexOf(each)))
}

findDifferentElements(array1(each => JSON.stringify(each.slice(1))), array2(each => JSON.stringify(each)))
```

Any help to solve this is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to explain the requirement more. Give a brief explanation of your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need output as [
  [ { i1: 5, j1: 4 }, { i2: 6, j2: 4 } ],
  [ { i1: 6, j1: 5 }, { i2: 1, j2: 5 } ]
], coordinates of different indexes in array1 and array2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it right that we need an array to store the position of the wrong index?

```js
const array1 = [
  ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
  ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
  ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
  ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,569.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
  ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTE", "Test1"],
];

const array2 = [
  ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
  ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTG", "Test1"],
  ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
  ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
  ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
  ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,500.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
];

/**
 * 
 * @param { string[][] } arr1
 * @param { string[][] } arr2
 * @returns { string[] }
 */
const findDifferentElements = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
    const targetIndex = arr2.findIndex((el) => el[0] === cur[0])
    const target = arr2[targetIndex]

    cur.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (item !== target[i]) acc.push(`[{${idx}, ${i}}, {${targetIndex}, ${i}}]`)
    })

    return acc
  }, [])
}

console.log(findDifferentElements(array1, array2))
```

Comment: hi @leteu thanks for the response, your code snippet works great! but if I am not wrong it assumes that the first element (Tom1, Tom2, ..) of each array inside array1/array2 remains the same. I am right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is the case assuming that array1 element and array2 element have the same first element.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my array it could change. I am trying to figure how to do that. would be great if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: @Safi what does that mean? `Tomx` could at different index or for example `Tom1` could become `Tom11`?

Comment: @Safi If there is no primary key. you can't diff array.

Comment: @leteu yes Tom1 could become Tom11. Is there no way to solve this without primary key?

Comment: @Safi You mean array1[0][0] is not same array2[0][0] right? This isn't a problem. my code find array2[n] where array1[0][0] is same array2[n][0]

Comment: @leteu array1[0][0], array2[3][0] could be same or different, our code has to find its coordinates if they are different.

Comment: @Safi if `array1[0][0]` is `Tom1` my code find `array2[n]` from `array2` where `Tom1` in index is `0`. You mean you want exception handling when can't find in `array2`?

Answer (score 0):

I made up as per my understanding.

```
const array1 = [
      ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
      ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
      ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
      ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
      ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
      ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,569.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
      ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTE", "Test1"],
    ];

    const array2 = [
      ["Tom2", "png", "Test3", "TRUE", "3,452.00", "wer", "Test3"],
      ["Tom7", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,563.00", "RTG", "Test1"],
      ["Tom3", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "3,120.00", "edr", "Test1"],
      ["Tom1", "PNG", "Test1", "TRUE", "1,000.00", "abc", "Test1"],
      ["Tom4", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
      ["Tom5", "jpg", "Test2", "TRUE", "4,321.00", "fgt", "Test2"],
      ["Tom6", "jpg", "Test1", "TRUE", "4,500.00", "tgg", "Test5"],
    ];

    var output = [];
    var indexesInArray1 = []
var indexesInArray2 = []

    function getIndexOfK(arr, k) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
        if (index > -1) {
          return [i, index];
        }
      }
    }
    const findDifferentElements = (array1, array2) => {
      var indexesInArray1 = []
      var indexesInArray2 = []

      for(let i in array1) {
        for(let j in array1[i]){
            if(getIndexOfK(array2, array1[i][j]) == undefined) {
                indexesInArray1.push({i, j})
            }
        }
      }

      for(let i in array2) {
        for(let j in array2[i]){
            if(getIndexOfK(array1, array2[i][j]) == undefined) {
                indexesInArray2.push({i, j})
            }
        }
      }

      output.push(indexesInArray1, indexesInArray2);
      console.log(output)

    }

    findDifferentElements(array1, array2);
```

Try this and if you have any issue on my code, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @DevConductor for your response. your code works fine for one difference but if there is more diffrences, it doesn't give the index of array1. this is the output for 3 differences [
  [ { i: '2', j: '5' }, { i: '4', j: '4' } ],
  [ { i: '1', j: '4' }, { i: '4', j: '5' }, { i: '7', j: '5' } ]
]